# Angular (12) duplicates my global css variables

Tags: css, angular

I have create a new project using `@angular/cli` (12.2.13):

```
ng new test
```

I also said I wanted the configuration to be with `scss`.

In my `styles.scss`, I did add:

```
:root {
  --myVar: red;
}
```

I then run `ng build --configuration production`

and when I checked the resulting `index.html` in my `dist/` folder I have:

```
<style>:root{--myVar:red}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.b08f420056d5c4d3e83d.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"></style>
```

with `styles.b08f420056d5c4d3e83d.css` also containing `:root{--myVar:red}`

In production, it does result in having that css variable twice. Is there any way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see as an issue, is more like an advantage. The case that you describe in angular is called inlining critical styles. Angular checks for the most used values from your css and inlines it, to reduce [first contentful paint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First_contentful_paint) time.

If you want to disable it, edit your angular config (`angular.json`) in build section to have this:

```json
"optimization": {
    "styles": { 
        "inlineCritical": false 
    }
}
```

More in [angular.io docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-optimization-options).